# How to create code to count "blank" rows in R

Tags: r

I am working with timestamp data that has recorded a separate row for every caregiver recorded. The number of caregivers varies for each time stamp and the data file is very long so I need to find a way to calculate the number of caregivers for each time stamp.

Is there a line of code I can use to calculate the number of rows (caregivers) under each timestamp and appear under the column "No.Caregivers"

```
         Time   ID No.Caregivers
1  6:00:20 AM <NA>            NA
2               X1            NA
3               X2            NA
4               X3            NA
5               X4            NA
6  6:00:50 AM <NA>            NA
7               X1            NA
8               X2            NA
9  6:01:20 AM <NA>            NA
10              X1            NA
11              X2            NA
12              X3            NA
```

Comment: When you say "Is there a line of code" you're asking us to write code for you. Instead, the Stack Overflow way is for you to write code, testing it, doing that many times until you've exhausted your ideas, do more research, try that all again, THEN ask a question. Without code it looks like you didn't try which isn't a good starting point. Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" for more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option is to create a grouping column with cumulative sum of the non-NA elements of 'Time' (if it is `NA`).  If it is blank (`""`), use the cumulative sum of non-blank (`cumsum(Time != "")`)

```
library(dplyr)    
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(!is.na(Time)) %>%
    mutate(Count = n())
```

---

Or detect the nunber at the beginning

```
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(grp = cumsum(str_detect(Time, "^[0-9]")) %>%
    mutate(Count = n())
```